# The yearling badge

Tags: support, badges

I got the yearling badge today, yet on my profile it says I've been a member for a year and a half.

I initially thought the year and a half was my global profile or something but I've checked and my SO account has 1 year 9 months, so I don't think that's the case.

Why have I only just got the badge now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are *two* requirements for Yearling:

- a year old account, and
- **200 reputation.**

You only now got 200 reputation. Hence why you only now got your badge.

Comment: Ahh, I feel silly now! Thanks for the quick response. (will accept when I can)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett And in other news, congratulations!

Comment: Does this also mean, that if your account is 2 years old. And you get 200 reputation, you will get both the yearling badges?

Comment: @Dimitrimx yep, that's right